# PHP influxdb - get measurement name in result

Tags: php, influxdb

I need to get some data out of my influxdb database.
My current query is:

```
SELECT value FROM first,second,third WHERE location = 'somewhere' ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1
```

With this result:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
array(2) {
  ["time"]=>
  string(30) "2020-02-06T12:44:49.461551353Z"
  ["value"]=>
  float(8.7572979625)
}
[1]=>
array(2) {
  ["time"]=>
  string(29) "2020-02-06T12:44:48.70683539Z"
   ["value"]=>
  float(22.5172978864)
}
[2]=>
array(2) {
  ["time"]=>
  string(30) "2020-02-06T12:44:48.711272393Z"
  ["value"]=>
  float(43.0572978868)
}
}
```

To process this information i have to use a while loop of some sort, i am unsure since i cannot find an
example of this online anywhere related to this type of data. 
But to make the loop useful i need to know what the measurement name is, if i dont have that the result is quite unusable.

I would require this to be:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
array(2) {
  ["time"]=>
  string(30) "2020-02-06T12:44:49.461551353Z"
  ["measurement"]=>
  string(5) "first"
  ["value"]=>
  float(8.7572979625)
}
[1]=>
array(2) {
  ["time"]=>
  string(29) "2020-02-06T12:44:48.70683539Z"
  ["measurement"]=>
  string(6) "second"
  ["value"]=>
  float(22.5172978864)
}
[2]=>
array(2) {
  ["time"]=>
  string(30) "2020-02-06T12:44:48.711272393Z"
  ["measurement"]=>
  string(5) "third"
  ["value"]=>
  float(43.0572978868)
 }
}
```

How can i achieve this and process the results correctly?

Comment: Why don't you select from the 3 tables individually?

Comment: because i have about 35 columns, but what i found out now is that $result->getPoints(); in php masks the name of the measurement. When i print result i get the names, but now the issue is how to process the result. I cannot find an example on getPoints for a loop or i shouldn't use getPoints at all. The documentation doesnt state how to use it properly.

Comment: Why is having 35 columns a reason for not doing 3 queries?

Answer (score 0):

This solved my issue:

```
<?php
 include "vendor/autoload.php";

 $columns = array('first', 'second', 'third');
 $cstrings = implode(",",$columns);
 $database = InfluxDB\Client::fromDSN(sprintf('influxdb://xxx:xxx@%s:%s/%s', 'localhost', 8086, 'xxxx'));
 $client = $database->getClient();
 $result = $database->query("SELECT value FROM $cstrings WHERE location = 'xxx' ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1");

 foreach ($columns as $column) {
   $points = $result->getPoints($column);
   print($column." ".$points[0]['value']."\n");
 }
```